# Calculate sum of hours falling within a selected month for transactions spanning multiple months

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

Greetings of the day to all you brainy folks :slightly_smiling_face:
I am a basic user of powerquery, do not have powerBI installed. I could use your help with this issue I am struggling with.

I have a list of transactions (thousands of rows) that have an outage start time and end time, most of them spanning over multiple months.

| Number | Outage Began | Outage Ended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INC2536 | 1/4/2023 4:01 | 5/4/2023 9:01 |
| INC2537 | 1/4/2023 4:01 | 1/4/2023 9:01 |
| INC2538 | 2/8/2023 9:46 | 4/15/2023 11:01 |
| INC2539 | 3/24/2023 16:35 | 5/24/2023 20:28 |
| INC2540 | 5/28/2023 16:21 | 7/3/2023 17:38 |
| INC2541 | 6/4/2023 8:25 | 6/4/2023 9:42 |
| INC2542 | 6/17/2023 9:25 | 6/17/2023 13:00 |
| INC2543 | 6/17/2023 9:25 | 6/18/2023 11:33 |
| INC2544 | 6/17/2023 9:25 | 7/18/2023 11:33 |

I need to calculate the count of Incidents and the sum of outage hours that fall within a certain month, say Apr'23. In other words, if I filter my Pivot to Apr'23, it should only give me the count and sum for the Incidents that have some of the time during Apr'23.
Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out myself.
Copying the solution here in case anyone else comes searching and hits this thread:

```
List.DateTimes ([Outage Began],Duration.TotalHours ([Outage Ended]-[Outage Began])+1,#duration(0,1,0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**